# Converting UTC GMT+0200 to local time

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to convert my UTC dates stored as `DateTime` in `SQL Server` to the **local** **DateTime** of the client.

I have a date that is stored in my database as UTC and it's value is `2017-01-10 10:52:07.820`.

Using the code below it appears appears as `Tue Jan 10 2017 10:52:07 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)`

```
 var testDateUtc = moment(item.DatePosted); //"/Date(1484038327820)/"
 var localDate = moment(testDateUtc).local();           
 var d = localDate.toDate();              
 var DatePosted = d; //result is Tue Jan 10 2017 10:52:07 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)
```

I would like to the offset GMT+0200 to be added to the date so the final date looks like: Tue Jan 10 2017 **12**:52:07 or ideally formatting it as: `10/1/2017 12:52`

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a programming language to access SQLServer? I commend you for wanting to do this with a built-in function, time and date handling is unfortunately almost never simple

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave Yes, VB.NET through a class property 
    Public Property DatePosted() As System.Nullable(Of DateTime)
        Get
            Return m_DatePosted.Value.ToUniversalTime
        End Get
        Set(value As System.Nullable(Of DateTime))
            m_DatePosted = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_DatePosted As System.Nullable(Of DateTime)

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave The server is in a different timezone and clients in other timezones though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you input is in UTC you have to use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) mode when constructing moment object.

You can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to chose how to display moment objects.

Here a working example:

```js
var testDateUtc = moment.utc(1484038327820);
var localDate = moment(testDateUtc).local();
console.log(localDate.format('D/M/YYYY HH:mm'));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```